# Reading/writing to NSStream no matter what ViewController user is in

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am making a very basic iOS chat application, the app now has several different viewControllers so i now somehow want to always listen to the server no matter what viewController the user is on.

Before i had my NSStream code on the viewController that i wanted to update, however now since i have multiple views i want to make sure that the server is listening for updates no matter what viewController a user is on..

How can i do this? Where would i put my methods for listing / writing to the server (so that all viewControllers can read/write to it)?

Comment: Make a Delegate for this purpose and make every ViewController to conform to the delegate's protocol.

Comment: I see, so i should put my methods for this in my AppDelegate and then include it in each view?

Comment: No, that's not what `AppDelegate` is for.

Comment: Ok so i create a Object-c class file where i write my methods and include that in the views?

Answer (score 2):

You could make a global singleton that handles your chat connections and does all the reads and writes. All the view controllers that need to be able to send or receive chat messages would then use that singleton.

For how to communicate between the view controllers and your chat singleton, have a look at Apple's [Notification Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html) and [Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)

Don't abuse the `AppDelegate` for things like that. Just because it is a globally available singleton, does not mean it should handle everything that is shared between view controllers.

Your views should not know anything about chat connections.

Answer (score 1):

Create a singleton to manage the communication. Call it something like `XXChatDataController`. Be sure that none of the view controllers create their own instance.

If you have multiple view controllers you want to look at using notifications (instead of delegation) to distribute information about new chat data being received as this will allow your code to be simpler and to handle the situation where you have multiple view controllers observing updates at the same time (if you were using child view controllers say).

Comment: Then i include my singleton in each viewController to access the data?

Comment: By 'include', you mean 'import and get the `sharedInstance`', yes.

Comment: Ok cool, and in what view to i initialise the first instance so that it can be shared between all?

Comment: That doesn't matter, the first time you try to access the singleton it will be created. Use the `dispatch_once` code for that.

Comment: Do i simple create the singleton in a new object-c class file? if so; what should i subclass it to?

Comment: Yes, usually it would be a subclass of `NSObject`.